# Process RGB_565 bitmap in NDK

Tags: android, c++, bitmap, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm facing problem processing RGB_565 bitmaps. My code works fine for ARGB_8888:
Here are some code snippets I used for ARGB_8888(which works fine):

```
typedef struct
{

    uint8_t red;
    uint8_t green;
    uint8_t blue;
    uint8_t alpha;
} argb;
.....
.....        
void* pixelscolor;
    int ret;
    int y;
    int x;
    uint32_t *pixel;


    if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bmp, &infocolor)) < 0) {
        //return null;
    }

    if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bmp, &pixelscolor)) < 0) {
    }
    int width = infocolor.width;
    int height = infocolor.height;

    for (y = 0; y <  height; y++) {
        argb * line = (argb *) pixelscolor;
        for (int n = 0; n < width; n++) {
            int newValue = line[n].alpha+line[n].red+line[n].green+line[n].blue;
......
....
```

I get a result like this [ARGB_8888 results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dz6eX.png).

But when trying the RGB_565 format:

```
typedef struct
{

    uint8_t red;
    uint8_t green;
    uint8_t blue;

} rgb;
.....
.....        
void* pixelscolor;
    int ret;
    int y;
    int x;
    uint32_t *pixel;


    if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bmp, &infocolor)) < 0) {
        //return null;
    }

    if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bmp, &pixelscolor)) < 0) {
    }
    int width = infocolor.width;
    int height = infocolor.height;

    for (y = 0; y <  height; y++) {
        rgb * line = (rgb *) pixelscolor;
        for (int n = 0; n < width; n++) {
            int newValue = line[n].red+line[n].green+line[n].blue;
......
....
```

I get the following result:[RGB_565 result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMEkO.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RGB_565` uses just 2 bytes per pixel i.e. 16 bits:

```
 1         1
 5 4 3 2 1 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|   red   |   green   |  blue   |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

So to access separate color channels you can use next code:

```
uint16_t u16_pix;

red   = (u16_pix >> 11) & 0x1f;
green = (u16_pix >>  5) & 0x3f;
blue  = (u16_pix >>  0) & 0x1f;
```

To set them:

```
u16_pix = (red << 11) | (green << 5) | (blue);
```

Note, that you must ensure that color channels values must fit into their limits, i.e

```
red:   0 to 31
green: 0 to 63
blue:  0 to 31
```

Comment: thanks, this resolves the problem of duplication. but the quality of the results are not as good as the ARGB_8888 format. although, my program never use the alpha channel. anyway, many thanks :)